# How to replace Hi with Bye in a file

Tags: c++

I want to replace hi with a bye by reading a file and outputting another file with the replaced letters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream myfile;
    ofstream output;
    output.open("outputfile.txt");
    myfile.open("infile.txt");
    char letter;
    myfile.get(letter);
    while (!myfile.eof()) {
        if (letter == 'H') {
            char z = letter++;
            if (z == 'i')
            output << "BYE";
        }
        else output << letter;
    }

    output.close();
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My outputs are repeated capital I's that is repeated infinity times.

Here is my input file

```
Hi
a Hi Hi a 
Hi a a Hi
```

Comment: `letter++` doesn't get the next letter in the input stream.

Comment: `letter` is just a `char` like any other. It has no connection to the input stream you read it from. (What do you expect `char letter = 'H'; letter++;` to do?)

Comment: [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/) may be helpful.

Comment: Probably, it would be easier to read words (instead of char).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Don't check eof

The `eof` method is returning the location of the input stream read pointer, and not the status of the `get`. It is more like telling you whether or not `get` will succeed, so you could write something like:

```
    while (!myfile.eof()) {
        char letter;
        myfile.get(letter);
        //...
    }
```

In this way, you would at least be getting a new letter at each iteration, and the loop ends when the read pointer reaches the end of the input.

But, there are other cases that might cause the `get` to not succeed. Fortunately, these are captured by the stream itself, which is returned by `get`. Testing the status of the stream is as easy as treating the stream as a boolean. So, a more idiomatic way to write the loop is:

```
    char letter;
    while (myfile.get(letter)) {
        //...
    }
```

#### Peek at the next letter

When you want to look at the next letter in the input following the detected `'H'`, you perform an increment.

```
            char z = letter++;
```

But, this does not achieve the desired result. Instead, it just sets both `letter` and `z` variables to the numerical successor of `'H'` (`'H' + 1`), and does not observe the next letter in the input stream.

There is another method you can use that is like `get`, but leaves the input in the input stream. It is called `peek`.

```
            char z;
            auto peek = [&]() -> decltype(myfile) {
                    if (myfile) z = myfile.peek();
                    return myfile;
            };
            if (peek()) {
               //...
            }
```

And now, you can check the value of `z`, but it is still considered input for the next `get` on `letter`.

#### Close to what you implemented

So, the complete loop could look like:

```
    char letter;
    while (myfile.get(letter)) {
        if (letter == 'H') {
            char z;
            auto peek = [&]() -> decltype(myfile) {
                    if (myfile) z = myfile.peek();
                    return myfile;
            };
            if (peek() && z == 'i') {
                myfile.get(z);
                output << "BYE";
                continue;
            }
        }
        output << letter;
    }
```

With this approach, you will be able to correctly handle troublesome cases like `HHi` as input, or the last letter in the input being an `H`.

Comment: This is tight and handles those problems you mentioned. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Your two lines:

```
myfile.get(letter);
while (!myfile.eof()) {
```

are wrong.

First off you only read `letter` once, hence your infinite loop.
Secondly you don't use `eof` in a `while` loop.

You want something more like:

```
while (myfile.get(letter)) {
```

Also:

```
char z = letter++;
```

is wrong, you want to read another `letter`:

```
myfile.get(z);
```

but you have to be careful that you get something, so

```
if(!myfile.get(z)) {
    output << letter;
    break;
}
```

So finally:

```
char letter;
while (myfile.get(letter)) {
    if (letter == 'H') {
        char z;
        if(!myfile.get(z)) {
            output << letter;
            break;
        }
        if (z == 'i') {
            output << "BYE";
        }
        else output << letter << z;
    }
    else output << letter;
}
```

But now we are consuming the character after any `H` which may not be desirable.
See @jxh's answer for a way to do this with look ahead.

Comment: Is HHi supposed to become HBYE or not? OP has not specified.

Comment: @jxh Just showing how to get the OP code working, there are things like `HHi` not addressed by the OP. Reading lines and using a regex find and replace with word boundaries might be a better approach.

Comment: The program as written by OP seems to want to process one letter at a time with a look ahead. But the intended behavior is not documented.

Comment: The program is supposed to read Hi and output BYE. The code above works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated function to replace patterns in strings. For example, you could use `std::regex_replace`. That is very simple. We define, what should be searched for and with what that would be replaced.

Some comments. On StackOverflow, I cannot use files. So in my example program, I use a `std::istringstream` instead. But this is also an `std::istream`. You can use any other `std::istream` as well. So if you define an `std::ifstream` to read from a file, then it will work in the same way as the `std::istringstream`. You can simply replace it. For the output I use the same mechanism to show the result on the console.

Please see the simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>

// The source file
std::istringstream myfile{ R"(Hi
a Hi Hi a 
Hi a a Hi)" };

// The destination file
std::ostream& output{ std::cout };

int main() {
    // Temporary string, to hold one line that was read from a file
    std::string line{};

    // Read all lines from the file
    while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {

        // Replace the sub-string and write to output file
        output << std::regex_replace(line, std::regex("Hi"), "Bye") << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach. The only objection I have to the answer is that it doesn't attempt to explain specific problems in the code presented by the OP.